# Where to ask question

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I have asked [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/37753/need-help-optimizing-a-ruby-code?noredirect=1#comment62696_37753) first on Stack Overflow but then someone said it's off-topic and I should ask it on Code Review. Now on Code Review the question seems is again off-topic. Where should I ask it after all?

Comment: From the comments at Code Review, it seems that this question probably doesn't have a place within the Stack Exchange network. Perhaps [Where can I ask questions that don't fit or are off-topic for Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8401) has some useful resources for you.

Comment: From this link my code should be either on stackoverflow or on codereview. I personally don't agree with the statement that it is off topic on either of them, but I want to hear some **constructive** comments. It does not belong here because you did not write it makes no sense to me. What should i do re write the code and ask the question again? We are supposed to help users right?

Comment: I don't disagree; I was just re-iterating the advice you'd already received. I'm not making a judgment either way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Addressing your comment to this question here on MSO:

> It does not belong here because you did not write it makes no sense to me.

The problem about writing code on Code Review that doesn't originate from you is that on Stack Exchange, all content is licensed under a Creative Commons license. Writing code on a Stack Exchange site that isn't yours is problematic since **you are not legally allowed to do that**. You don't own the licensing of that code.

Therefore, it is not so much about us not being helpful, it is about us trying to protect you - legally speaking.

This topic has also been brought up on Code Review's meta site: [Why is only my own written code on-topic?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1294/why-is-only-my-own-written-code-on-topic)

Comment: Now that is a good reason that i agree with.

Answer (score 3):

### What is the question ?

It is a code review. So it doesn't belong to Stack Overflow. They were right to point you to Code Review.

### Does it belong on Code Review now ?

No it doesn't. Why ?

*From the Help Center*

> Simply ask yourself the following questions. To be on-topic the answer must be yes to all questions:
>
> Does my question contain code? (Please include the code in the question, not a link to it)
> Did I write that code?
> Is it actual code from a project rather than pseudo-code or example code?
> Do I want the code to be good code, (i.e. not code-golfing, obfuscation, or similar)
> To the best of my knowledge, does the code work?
> Do I want feedback about any or all facets of the code?

Since it is not your code, it doesn't.

> - @izomorphius not on StackExchange. write your own code and then you can have it reviewed here, otherwise you are submitting someone else's code under cw licensing or something like that, and that could be illegal
> - This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing someone else's code

I think the comments are pretty clear about what the issue is with the post.

Comment: you honestly believe this is what i should do? re-write the same code with some slight modifications and ask the exact same question again? Isn't stackexchange about helping users? I believe rules should be asked where it makes sense

Comment: `you honestly believe this is what i should do?`. I'm not the one making the rules. I hang on meta because I like applying them and trying to help others around the network. I'm sorry if you are against these rules maybe you could try openning a question about this on the Code Review Meta page but I'm not sure it will be received positively.

Comment: @insertcleverxmasname There's already been a meta question on Code Review about this: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1294/why-is-only-my-own-written-code-on-topic

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg Thanks wasnt aware :)